# image hover overlay, ahref on second click needed for mobile website

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover, overlay

EDITED:
 
1) desktop size: hover overlay works, a click on img leads to the website.

2) mobile size: hover doesn't work, a click on img does both overlay and goes straight to the website (I don't want that).

3) I want mobile size to behave ALMOST same as desktop size, overlay then a second click to lead to the website.

Tried: Added second ahref "Click to enter" inside IMAGE while having first ahref with "#/" for overlay purpose, doesn't work. Any better solution?

https://jsfiddle.net/6ro92ao9/

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
      <a href="http://codepen.io/ngarciaiii/full/Vjwjbp/">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0IGbqui.jpg" alt = "Web Ex1" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
              <h2 class="text">HTML5 CSS3</h2>
            </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.gallery:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here.

Comment: @BriennaHerold 1) desktop size: hover overlay works, a click on img leads to the website. <br/>   2) mobile size: hover doesn't work, a click on img does both overlay and goes straight to the website. <br/>  3) I want mobile to act almost same as desktop size, overlay then a second click to lead to the website.

Comment: So you want an overlay to appear when you hover, and this is happening in desktop but not mobile? It would need a workaround, because in mobile :hover behavior doesn't exist. http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Comment: So are you saying that for mobile, you want the first click to display the overlay, but not do anything else, and the second click to navigate to the main site?

Comment: @TripeHound Yes! Thank you for simplifying my question.

Comment: Solved this problem by using '#/" for first `a href`, and actual link in second a href. Allows overlay to happen on touch screen without going directly into website automatically.